# How can I group object keys based their value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object like below

```
var score = { 'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 1 };
```

I want to create another object with key, value swapped and same valued keys grouped together, like below.

```
{ 1:['A', 'C'], 2: 'B' };
```

I dont want the single values, like 'B', inside an array. I want them alone.
Please help.

Hi thanks for the answers. Finally to remove the array syntax if there is only one element i did the following.

```
$.each(obj, function(key, arr){
    if(arr.length == 1){
    obj[key] = arr[0]
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where specifically are you stuck? You must have *some* thoughts about how to solve this problem...

Comment: Then why not "fix" this up after the fact? Iterate over the new object and change all properties with single element arrays with to the element itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swap key with value in object](//stackoverflow.com/q/23013573/90527)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution, using `Array#forEach`.

```js
var score = { 'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 1 }, hash = {};
    Object.keys(score).forEach(v => (hash[score[v]] || (hash[score[v]] = [])).push(v));
    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(hash));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```js
var score = { 'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 1 };

var obj = {};
for(var i in score) {
   if(!obj[score[i]]) {
   obj[score[i]] = [i];
   } else {
 obj[score[i]].push(i);
   }
}

console.log(obj);
```

**EDIT:**

In the case when you don't want array for a single element, you can use this:

```js
var score = { 'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 1, 'D':1 };
    var obj = {};
    for (var i in score) {
        if (!obj[score[i]]) {
            obj[score[i]] = i;
        } else {
            var temp = obj[score[i]];
            if (Object.prototype.toString.call(temp) === "[object Array]") {
                obj[score[i]].push(i);
            } else {
                obj[score[i]] = [];
                obj[score[i]].push(temp);
                obj[score[i]].push(i);
            }
        }
    }
    
    console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks..but I dont want an array if its a single valued key

Answer (score 0):

```js
var score = {
  'A': 1,
  'B': 2,
  'C': 1
};

var group = Object.keys(score).reduce(function(a, b) {
  var vKey = score[b];
  a[vKey] = a[vKey] || [];
  a[vKey].push(b);
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(group);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution uses some more recent Javascript language features: object spread, array spread, computed property names, and the array `concat` method. Note that this method does not return an array for a single value as the question specifies.

```js
const s = { 'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 1 };

const o = Object.keys(s).reduce((a, k) =>
  ({...a, ...{[s[k]]: a[s[k]] ? [...a[s[k]]].concat(k) : k}}), {});

console.log(o);
```

The same solution is shown below, just fleshed out a little for more readability. It also includes an additional value (`'D': 1`) in the `score` which, if you pull apart the answer, shows the needs for the array spread. The comments show how the variable values change in each iteration through the loop.

```js
const score = { 'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 1, 'D': 1 };

const invertedScore = Object.keys(score).reduce((acc, key) => {
                          // iter'n#:   0     1      2            3
                          // key:      'A'   'B'    'C'          'D'
  const val = score[key]; // val:       1     2      1            1
  const prev = acc[val];  // prev:    undef undef   'A'       ['A','C']
  const chgd = prev ? [...prev].concat(key) : key;
                          // chgd:     'A'   'B'   ['A','C']  ['A','C','D']
  return ({...acc, ...{[val]: chgd}});
}, {});

console.log(invertedScore);
```